# How to create Table names and column names with lower case letter in server JIRA plugin?

Tags: database, spring, jira

I am using AO and all the table names I specify are converted to upper case . I want all the names in lower case .

`Entity class Example :`

```
@Table("activity_logger")  
public interface ActivityLoggerEntity extends Entity {

@Mutator("start_time")
public void setStartTime(Timestamp Timestamp);

@Accessor("start_time")
public Timestamp getStartTime();
```

Comment: Why do you want all names in lower case?

Comment: We are supporting multiple database . But postgresql does not work untill and unless we surround Table names and column names with Double quotes with names in upper case letters as JIRA AO does it internally . This will be an overhead for complex query & can't go this way .

Comment: Where is the overhead you're worried about? All other plugins are in the same situation. At least within an AO context, you shouldn't need to double-quote anything. Can you provide an example of what doesn't work?